# Symfony2 custom user provider authenticate after refresh

Tags: php, security, symfony, service, provider

Hi my problem is that i set up custom user provider, when i want to login it return me error:
`there is no user provider for user`

```
There is no user provider for user "MainBundle\Security\User\SsoUser".
```

but when i pres F5 to refresh page it works!
why is that where is a problem ?
my settings are:

```
    secured_area:
        pattern: ^/
        simple_preauth:
            authenticator: sso_authenticator
```

and my autenticator class:

```
/**
 * @Service("sso_authenticator")
 */
class SsoAuthenticator implements SimplePreAuthenticatorInterface
{

    /**
     * @var SsoUserProvider
     */
    protected $userProvider;

    /**
     * @InjectParams({
     *      "userProvider" = @Inject("sso_user_provider")
     * })
     */
    public function __construct(SsoUserProvider $userProvider)
    {
        $this->userProvider = $userProvider;
    }

    public function createToken(Request $request, $providerKey)
    {
        $user = $request->getSession()->get('sso_user');

        if (!$user) {
            throw new BadCredentialsException('No user found');
        }

        return new PreAuthenticatedToken(
                'anon.', $user, $providerKey
        );
    }

    public function authenticateToken(TokenInterface $token, UserProviderInterface $userProvider, $providerKey)
    {
        $user = $token->getCredentials();

        $sso_user = $this->userProvider->loadUser($user);

        return new PreAuthenticatedToken(
                $sso_user, $user, $providerKey, $sso_user->getRoles()
        );
    }

    public function supportsToken(TokenInterface $token, $providerKey)
    {
        return $token instanceof PreAuthenticatedToken && $token->getProviderKey() === $providerKey;
    }

}
```

SsoUserProvider class:

```
/**
 * @Service("sso_user_provider")
 */
class SsoUserProvider implements UserProviderInterface
{

    public function loadUser($user)
    {
        return new SsoUser($user['id'], $user['username'], $user['password'], null, $user['email'], array('ROLE_USER'));
    }

    public function loadUserByUsername($username)
    {
        throw new \RuntimeException('Method unsupported');
    }

    public function refreshUser(UserInterface $user)
    {
        if (!$user instanceof SsoUser && !$this->supportsClass(get_class($user))) {
            throw new UnsupportedUserException(sprintf('Instances of "%s" are not supported.', get_class($user)));
        }

        return $user;
    }

    public function supportsClass($class)
    {
        return $class === 'MainBundle\\Security\\User\\SsoUser';
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i edited `authenticateToken()` method like this and it works now:

public function authenticateToken(TokenInterface $token, UserProviderInterface $userProvider, $providerKey)
{
    $user = $token->getCredentials();
    if (!is_array($user)) {
        $user = $token->getUser();
    }

```
if (!$user) {
    throw new AuthenticationException('User does not exist.');
}

$ssoUser = $this->userProvider->loadUser($user);

return new PreAuthenticatedToken(
        $ssoUser, $user, $providerKey, $ssoUser->getRoles()
);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Can you disable these three lines and check again if this bug occures?

```
if (!$user instanceof SsoUser && !$this->supportsClass(get_class($user))) {
            throw new UnsupportedUserException(sprintf('Instances of "%s" are not supported.', get_class($user)));
        }
```

I feel that there might be a problem with `$user` type or `!$this->supportsClas` <- should there be a '!' sign?

Comment: nothing changes if i disable all 3 lines or if i disable only this `!$this->supportsClass(get_class($user)` statement

Comment: Have you checked if symfony calls your code? You can do it by adding die or debuging

Comment: i think it doesnt call `createToken()` method

Comment: full stack: it works like this when i login it creates token and it authenticated and next in method `authenticateToken` calling `$token->getCredentials()` returns null. it doesnt keep user there